# Investigating whether a pointwise convergence of a series of functions is uniform

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, sequence-of-function

I am dealing with the convergence of the following series:

$ \sum_{n=1}^ \infty  (x^n,(1-x)^n) $

I already showed that, though not sure, this series of functions converge pointwisely to the function $f(x)= ( \frac{1}{1-x} ,  \frac{1}{x}  )$ on $(0,1)$, but diverges at $x=0,1$.  I used the convergence (or divergence) of the real series $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty  x^n $ and $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty  (1-x)^n$. Is this correct?

More importantly, I want to argue that this convergence is uniform (or not) on certain subsets of $(0,1)$. I could not find a promising approach so far. I tried to measure the distance between the sequence of partial sums and the limit function using the supremum norm when arguing but maybe Weierstrass Test is more convenient?

Comment: $f(x)= ( \frac{x}{1-x} ,  \frac{1-x}{x}  )$. The convergence is uniform on $[r,s]$ if $0<r<s<1$.

Comment: Right, I confused the convergence because I started from $n=1$ instead of $n=0$. Could you provide a hint for showing the uniform convergence?